# Optimal image quality using Rasterize Function

Tags: graphics, programming

Based on previous posts about  plotting two y axes on the same x axis, I wrote this function:

```
plotyy[x_, y1_, y2_] := Module[{xy1, xy2, p1, p2},
  xy1 = Table[{x[[i]], y1[[i]]}, {i, Length[x]}];
  xy2 = Table[{x[[i]], y2[[i]]}, {i, Length[x]}];
  p1 = ListLinePlot[xy1, ImagePadding -> 25, 
    Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, Axes -> False];
  p2 = ListLinePlot[xy2, ImagePadding -> 25, Axes -> False, 
    Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
    FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, PlotStyle -> Red];
  Rasterize[Overlay[{p1, p2}], RasterSize -> 600, ImageSize -> 600]]
```

which takes three lists with the same length and plots y1 and y2 on x. I've values for image quality by `RasterSize` and `ImageSize` for using the plot in my report but for different plots it may need different values for those two options.

How can I can set the optimum values for `RasterSize` and `ImageSize` in my function?

Thanks,
Amin.

Answer (score 1):

Good to know how to auto-adjust the optimum value.

However, when auto-adjust value does not satisfy our demands, we could adjust the values, and see which is best.

Another Option is `ImageResolution`
For Example:

```
plotyy[x_,y1_,y2_,a_,b_]:=Module[{xy1,xy2,p1,p2},xy1=Table[{x[[i]],y1[[i]]},    {i,Length[x]}];
xy2=Table[{x[[i]],y2[[i]]},{i,Length[x]}];
p1=ListLinePlot[xy1,ImagePadding->25,Frame->{True,True,False,False},Axes->False];
p2=ListLinePlot[xy2,ImagePadding->25,Axes->False,Frame->{False,False,False,True},FrameTicks->{None,None,None,All},PlotStyle->Red];
Rasterize[Overlay[{p1,p2}],RasterSize->500+a,ImageSize->600,ImageResolution->500+b]]

GraphicsGrid@Table[plotyy[{{1,1},{2,2}},{{3,3},{4,2}},{{2,2},{3,3}},a,b],{a,0,200,50},{b,0,200,50}]
```

of course, you could use `Manipulate` to adjust without too many pictures.